# Consistent form of these items in a list

Tags: verbs, nouns

In, say, a business context, I am making a list regarding application settings:

The levels of settings are:

- The **setting of** zones...
- The **management** of ...

Are these words both nouns here and therefore the list is consistent?

vs.

The levels of settings are:

- Setting zones ...
- Managing ....

Here, are both word now verbs and hence the list is still consistent? I guess I'm a little thrown off whether since **setting** hasn't changed spelling. Does using the word **the** require a noun to follow immediately afterwards?

Please indicate what area of English this question pertains to so I can explore further

Comment: Both lists look good to me, using parallel construction, but you repeat, "setting", i.e. "... settings are: The setting zones..." For that reason, you might try a synonym for one of them, perhaps, "defining zones"?

Comment: Could you complete the sentences? I'm having a hard time understanding what "levels of settings" means in this context

Comment: Here's something you should always try to follow (because ALL major style guides say so) - make sure that what precedes the colon is a complete sentence. You should write *"The levels of settings are as follows [or the following]:"*

Comment: So therefore am I correct about my grammatical thinking and explanations?

Comment: I thought the whole point of using a colon is to indicate that the completion of the  sentence follows after the colon. Does adding as follows make the sentence complete?